# Comparing dataset value

Tags: c#, winforms

In winform I am trying to compare the returned dataset value to defined value but I am getting following error.

[image: Visual Studio Error]

In the code below, I am passing the string from listbox to the GetStock method

```
public bool checkStock()
        {
            foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(GetStock(listBoxItem.ToString())) == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(listBoxItem.ToString() + " not in Stock!. Please delete the item before proceeding");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Code for GetStock()

```
 public DataSet GetStock(string product)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

            try
            {
                oleConn.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT [Quantity] FROM [Product] WHERE [Product Name]='" + product + "'";
                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oleConn);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Product");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                oleConn.Close();
            }
            if (dataSet.Tables["Product"].Rows.Count <= 0)
                return null;

            return dataSet;
        }

    }
}
```

In database the "Quantity" is in string format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetStock` returns a `DataSet` but you're passing it to `Convert.ToInt32`:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(GetStock(listBoxItem.ToString())) == 0)
```

You probably want something like this:

```
int stockCount = GetStockQuantity(listBoxItem.ToString());
if (stockCount == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show(listBoxItem.ToString() + " not in Stock!. Please delete the item before proceeding");
}
```

Here is the modified method(note that i'm using parameters)

```
public int GetStockQuantity(string product)
{
    int quantity = 0;
    string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 [Quantity] FROM [Product] WHERE [Product Name] = ?";
    using(var oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
    using(var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql , oleConn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", product);
        try
        {
            oleConn.Open();
            object obj_quantity = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if(obj_quantity != null)
                // "In database the "Quantity" is in string format." 
                // Change it to int if possible
                int.Parse((string)obj_quantity);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    return quantity;
}
```

Comment: but here I am referring 0 to when the quantity becomes 0

Comment: @AmritSharma: Edited my answer, although in my opinion it's better to return an empty `DataTable` or `DataSet`. Since you are selecting a single table i would return a DataTable instead, a DataSet suggests that it contains (or can contain) multiple tables.

Comment: implemented your solution but the code returns true even though I set quantity as 0 in database

Comment: @AmritSharma: You don't need to use a `DataSet`/`DataTable` when you just select a count, then use `ExecuteScalar`. Edited my answer accordingly. Also, always use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection or localization/formatting issues.

Comment: @AmritSharma: Do you want the quantity of the first product with a given product? By now it's possible that the query returns multiple rows, then you would get nan exception. In T-SQL or Access it's `SELECT TOP 1 Quantity ...`.

Comment: @AmritSharma: Only just seen this: _"In database the "Quantity" is in string format."_ Of course it should be `int`, but if it's not possible to change it you have to use htis code to parse it: `quantity = int.Parse((string)obj_quantity);`

Answer (score 1):

The `GetStock` method returns a `DataSet`, but you need the actual `int` value. Try this:

```
Convert.ToInt32(GetStock(listBoxItem.ToString()).Tables["Product"].Rows[0]["Quantity"])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
var count = GetStock(listBoxItem.ToString());

if (count > 0)
{
  //TODO: other stuff
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show(listBoxItem.ToString() + " not in Stock!. Please delete the item before proceeding");
}
```